# Parallel rendering in VTK

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, vtk

I have dynamic scene what I would like to render in a VTK window (QT, VC++ 2015 application). Objects in the scene are pointcoulds with hundreds of thousands points. Scene consists of:

- House (~800,000 points),
- Car (~700,000 points),
- Tree (~1,500,000 points).

Pointclouds are constantly generated at 30 fps in 3 separate threads. In the end all 3 pointclouds are merged in a 3 million pointcloud and rendered with a typical VTK code: vtkPoints -> vtkPolyData ->vtkPolyDataMapper -> etc.

Problem is that performance is very poor and it hardly reaches 4 fps on my PC.

How can I parallelize rendering of separate data streams in a single VTK window? Multiple mappers? Multiple actors? vtkParallelRenderManager?

Thanks in advance,
Sal

Comment: Did you ever reach a solution?